# Can someone explain to me exactly why it's bad to use NS name that is a subdomain for the domain that NS is for

Tags: domain-name-system, internet, dns-hosting

Reading a book and it states that you should not register
nameserver names such as ns1.example.com for the domain
example.com as you'll create a catch-22 situation when looking up ns1.example.com etc.
I know what a catch-22 is, but I just don't see how this fits in.

At which stage does this occur exactly, when internet central directory queries whois records
for that domain to find nameserver ip ?

excerpt from "The difinitive guide to CentOS (APress)"

> **Caution**  As you can imagine, telling the world that the primary DNS
>   server for example.org is dns0. example.org has some issues. Mainly,
>   this has you running around in circles because you’ve created a
>   catch-22 situation. You cannot look up dns0.example.org because to do
>   so you need to ask dns0. example.org. Now, as long as you have name
>   servers in another domain, this will still work, but it’s clearly a
>   bad idea. Stay away from this one, and if you have to, use a so-called
>   glue record that defines dns0.example.org in the parent .org zone to
>   solve the issue.

Comment: I find this very odd, what book was it from? The nameservers for `serverfault.com` are `ns1.serverfault.com`, `ns2.serverfault.com` and `ns3.serverfault.com`. That sort of thing is fairly standard practice (Even Google do it). Unless I've miss-understood the question

Comment: updated..........

Comment: funny book. clearly most of domains are set this way. Glue records is not some cheap _workaround_, that is how DNS designed to work.

Comment: Btw, it's _NS_ records, have little to do with WHOIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply not true to say that doesn't work, or causes problems.  For example, on my main domain:

```
[madhatta@www tmp]$ whois teaparty.net
[Querying whois.verisign-grs.com]
[Redirected to whois.tucows.com]
[Querying whois.tucows.com]
[whois.tucows.com]
[...]
 Domain servers in listed order:
    NS.TEAPARTY.NET   193.219.118.102
    NS2.TEAPARTY.NET   78.46.204.154
[...]
```

which works just fine.  The technical elements that makes this work are the [glue records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glue_records#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records), which you can read about at the link above, and elsewhere.

Comment: I'd go further than that:  Not only is it not true to say that it is bad practice, it is a _good_ practice that one _should_ adopt.